# Laravel - Image source not readable after publish website

Tags: image, laravel, upload, content-management-system

I was created simple CMS and everything works at localhost. After published website I can't upload image. I have an error "Image source not readable". I changed chmod upload's folder to 777.
My code:

```
$minphoto_path = 'uploads/img';
        $minphoto = $request->minphoto;
        $minphoto_new_name = time().$minphoto->getClientOriginalName();
        $minphoto->move($minphoto_path, $minphoto_new_name);

        $img = Image::make(public_path($minphoto_path . '/' .$minphoto_new_name))->resize(240, 338)->save(public_path($minphoto_path . '/' .$minphoto_new_name));
```

Comment: does it work now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try upload that way:

```
$file = Input::file('file');
$fileName = time() . '-' . $file->getClientOriginalName();

$file->move('uploads', $fileName);

$img = Image::make($file->getRealPath())->resize(320, 240)
    ->save('public/uploads/'. $file->getClientOriginalName());
```

Or shorter:

```
$file = Input::file('file');
$img = Image::make($file)->resize(320, 240)
    ->save('public/uploads/'. $file->getClientOriginalName());
```

Comment: Now i have this error "Quality must range from 0 to 100.". I want to resize img too.

Comment: Jest, I know. I tryed this but I have this same error "Quality must range from 0 to 100.". I trued ->quality(100) but it doesn't work.

Comment: ooooh it was typo in code, should be "." instead of "," look now at code, not: save('public/uploads/', $file->getClientOriginalName()); but: ->save('public/uploads/'. $file->getClientOriginalName());